# How to Install LLDB on Mac?

Tags: macos, lldb

I'm new to Mac, I would like to know how to Install LLDB on MAC.
I'm running the OS X 10.11 El Capitan GM.
I need to debug one of my friends Application on iOS.

I would like to instead of using xcode, have only a Window that looks like terminal but is LLDB. Any idea on how to do that? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Without installing Xcode, Open `terminal`, put `lldb` and press return. you will be prompt to the installation.