# running .sh file with Xcode ,i use terminal and everything work , no idea how to do this with xcode

Tags: c, xcode, compilation

I really need to use the debugger in Xcode but I can't get to make this work. I use the terminal on Mac, to compile a file, which I usually just change the directory and then I have .sh file and I write that down and everything compile, note this is what is in .sh file :

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "cleaning directory"
rm mag_test.out

echo "Compiling mag_cal_driver.c"
g++ -o mag_test.out mag_cal_driver.c ../src/mag_utils.c

echo -e "Running magnetometer tests\n"
./mag_test.out
```

how can I achieve this in Xcode ???? note the code is in c! 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkbFx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSXni.png)

Comment: what is your xcode version?

Comment: the version is 8.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For

```
rm mag_test.out
```

In MAC

```
make clean
```

Save the file as .c and type in the terminal:

```
gcc -o yourfilename yourfilename.c
```

or

```
 make yourfilename
```

Afterwards just run the executable like this:

```
./yourfilename
```

For debugging

You can use lldb

```
$ lldb yourfilename
```

break point

```
$breakpoint set --file yourfilename .c --line 12
```

Best is xcode interface for debugging (IDE)

For Installing LLDB follow
[LLDB INSTALLATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680789/how-to-install-lldb-on-mac)

For Guide use 
[LLDB GUIDE](https://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)

IF you want to use xcode IDE follow the step
1.Start xcode

2. Select Create new Xcode Project
3. Select Command line tool

[image: command line]

4.Select the language

[image: Language selection]

5.Create and add File and breakpoint as you like(blue arrow marked is debug break point)

6.After that just play the execute button at top most left corner

[image: debug]

Comment: hey does any body actually read what i wrote , i know how to compile it , as you saw in .sh file it do that , exactly ! how i do it in xcode ??? i need to use the debugger !

Comment: mybe i wrote it bad , but i know how to compile it using the terminal , how to compile it in xcode ?, so i be able to use Xcode debugger ??

Comment: i just saw your new edit ,  i see i can see how to do LLDB but i really want to be able to do it in xcode since it has graphic interface which make my life much easier in the end !

Comment: @HamidrezaRezai added steps let me know if you are struck anywhere

Comment: the problem lies i knew how to do this , but that is if i write my code in here, my code is already written and is in a folder with many other .c file and it will use many other library and some other data file, when i use terminal and compile it it compile and everything works , but i cant make it work to add it somehow to xcode that it compile . also thanks for helping me !

Comment: @HamidrezaRezai was the old code is xcode project or some other file

Comment: no it was not a Xcode project, i used notepad++ to write it !

Comment: If you just want to add files use Add files to (your project)

Comment: i edited my original post and added a pic to it as you see thats the folder i have , i need to compile mag_cal_driver.c but what ever i do i cant be able to i deleted the main which does create automatically but weren't able to make that file the main!

Comment: @HamidrezaRezai Your code is from git ..there is one more easy way .start xcode->checkout an existing project  (place your git path)

Comment: i used that option , it only downloaded the files nothing else it didnt added it to any project or anything !