# getting "MIDebuggerPath" error setting up VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

i am struggling to get my vscode working. it pops up this error.
"Unable to start debugging. Launch options string provided by the project system is invalid. Unable to determine path to debugger.  Please specify the Unable to start debugging. Launch options string provided by the project system is invalid. Unable to determine path to debugger.  Please specify the "MIDebuggerPath" option. option."

the code should be working alright, but there must be something im missing and my research in youtube tutorials was not very helpful.

pd im using OSX

here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "lldb-mi",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main"
            },
            "windows": {
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "gdb.exe",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main.exe"
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, it was solved by installing GDB (it does not come bundled with VS Code). In your case it seems like it is looking for lldb, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680789/how-to-install-lldb-on-mac) as a stackoverflow question that discusses installing lldb on osx.

Comment: FYI: if you're macOS Apple Chip users then GDB will not work for you. Use LLDB instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have `gdb` installed, you need to set `"miDebuggerPath"` to its full file name including the path, i.e. `"miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb"`.

Note that if `gdb` is installed normally (in a directory listed in `$PATH`), then you don't need to specify `"miDebuggerPath"` at all.

PS. Recent versions of VSCode seem to use `"gdbpath"` parameter instead of `"miDebuggerPath"`.